# Obtaining an API Key for GCM

Tags: android, api, key, api-key, google-cloud-messaging

I was trying to use Google Cloud Messaging for an Android application. In documentation it's said that I have to create new server key and here where I'm blocked. What's that ip address that I should enter to get my API KEY? I am for now using a free web hosting so I have no public IP address of my server-side application.

Can I instead use create new browser key? while it won't ask for an IP address.
Can you suggest something please?

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is the  ip address of your server where you will run the server side code for keeping the list of all registeration_id and sending  the sms to these registeration_id.

Comment: Can I use a domain name instead? I can't get an IP address :(

Comment: @lo2i sorry I gave up with this :/